# How to get the class type of nested generic type?

Tags: java, generics

Say we have a function:

```
void doSomething(Class<?> clazz);
```

If I want to call it for a class Foo, I would call it this way:

```
doSomething(Foo.class);
```

How do I call doSomething() if my type is **Foo<Boo>** ?

I guess the question is what is the equivalent of **Foo.class** for **Foo<Boo>**?

Is that even possible?

-- Update ---

I'll explain more.

I have a typed bean :

> class EventMessage`<T>`{
>
> T      payload;
>   String type;
>
> }

An object of this type gets converted to a Json form (String), then put on a JMS Queue;
The consumer needs to de-jasonize it back from the String to it's original form.
 The Json ObjectMapper needs to know the type to convert to. 
Say my EventMessage payload was Offer type, then I want something like that:

> EventMessage <Offer> offerEvent = jsonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonMsg,
>   EventMessage<Offer>.class)

Except that there is no such thing as `EventMessage<Offer>.class`.

The issue is that `EventMessage` is a typed class so the Json converter would have no idea how to resolve it without extra information about the payload type.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Long answer: Workarounds depend on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `Foo` class object. `Foo<Boo>` and `Foo<Integer>` are not different classes; they are the same class, and even if you could do `Foo<Boo>.class` it would be identical to `Foo` except for the compile-time type. But in the first example, you are not using the compile-time type anyway, since you are passing to a parameter of type `Class<?>`.

In your second example, you did not show the signature of `readValue()`, but I am assuming that it is something like `<T> T readValue(JSONMessage, Class<T>)`. This is completely different from your first example. In this case, the compile-time type helps determine the `T` which is the return type. You can either manipulate the type of the `Class` argument:

```
EventMessage<Offer> offerEvent =
    jsonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonMsg, (Class<EventMessage<Offer>>)
                                        (Class<?>)EventMessage.class)
```

or just use the raw type, get the raw type back, and let it be implicitly converted to the parameterized type:

```
EventMessage<Offer> offerEvent =
    jsonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonMsg, EventMessage.class)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
doSomething((Class<Foo<Boo>>)Foo.class)
```

Or this:

```
EventMessage<Offer> offerEvent = jsonObjectMapper.readValue(jsonMsg, 
                           (Class<EventMessage<Offer>>) EventMessage.class);
```

.class is a language literal, not a field. Maybe you like to report a feature-request to [java](http://bugs.java.com)

Comment: What does that gain you?  The type arguments on the `Class` won't be accessible to `doSomething`, I think.

Comment: The generic is more *generic*. After all it gains nothing. Maybe you dont need a @SuppressWarnings and checkstyle do not thread this as bad practice.

Comment: The method parameter is of type `Class<?>`.

Comment: The method parameter declaration is of type `Class<?>` the call can be of type `Class<Foo<Boo>>` afaik.

Comment: The type of the argument expression will be `Class<Foo<Boo>>` sure, but that gives us absolutely nothing.

Comment: The generic is more generic. After all it gives us absolutly nothing. Maybe you dont need a @SuppressWarnings and checkstyle do not thread this as bad practice.